# x-editable can I add a keypress event to input in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I would like to add a keypress or keyup event in x-editable and block the "-" button.
Is it possible to do it in x-editable?

here is code:

```
                <td class="col-xs-8"><a href="#" data-name="ten" id="ten" data-validate-type="ten" class="editable editable-click">{$user->ten}</a></td>
```

Comment: Hey @Crash can you give us some explain code, you can see too this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865315/x-editableselect-avoid-submitting-on-pressing-enter-key) and for the keyCode you can see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898129/javascript-subtract-keycode)

Comment: I found this solution before but I did not have a reaction when I clicked on the editable link. for this input, I want to block this key

Comment: Solved, thanks for help